# How can I submit disable input element in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, input

This `input` tag is disabled but I want to submit this form value.

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="400" class="field left" disabled />
```

Please help me about this tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can take this field as hidden. So it will not be visible and it will also be submitted in the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `readonly` instead of `disabled`

```
<input type="text" name="quantity"  value="400" class="field left" readonly />
```

If you still want it grayed out, you can set a background color:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="200" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;" readonly />
```

Comment: Its not disable the textbox. That's why user can edit this but I don't want this. I want user can see the value but can't edit. And submit the value.

Comment: The `readonly` attribute prevents the user from editing the textbox value.

Answer (score 2):

Use hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value=400>
```

Disabled one can be there too, just remove the name attribute.

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value=400>
<input type="text" value="400" class="field left" disabled>
```

Comment: The value didn't submit.

Answer (score 1):

Take hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity"  value="400" class="field left"/>
```

So it will not be visible and it will also be submitted in the form

Answer (score 1):

Use read-only and hidden to do this as disabled values cannot be submitted.If you do not want the user to edit the values ,then use a text element instead and read its value along the form using onsubmit attribute of form tag.